# What font is this?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, fonts

I'm on Linux Mint 16. Recently I saw a font I liked. I guess this was on Mac OS. What's it called? How do I install it on Mint?
[image]

Comment: This question would make more sense on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ IMHO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mac.

Comment: Considering the second part of the question is "how to install fonts on Mint", which is far more involved than determination of the font face, I don't think it's off-topic here. It's quite possibly a duplicate, though (I see quite a few similar questions in the sidebar).

Comment: @HaukeLaging, how do I know for sure it's Mac? If I was sure, I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: @Alex This is not about being sure. It's your guess, not mine. If you guess it's a Mac font then it obviously makes sense to ask on the Mac site first, doesn't it? Looks like a Mac screenshot to me, too.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, but it's about installing (if needed) this font on Mint, not Mac.

Comment: @Alex - that is most definitely a screenshot from OSX. Look at the red, yellow, green dots on the toolbar. The name of the machine is another clue, macbookair3.

Comment: @slm, yeah, I just spotted it, funny.

Comment: @HaukeLaging huh? OSX is perfectly on topic here, being about a mac is no reason to close a question! Mind you, "what's this font?" is still off topic since it's not a specific Linux or Unix problem but we don't close questions about mac just because they're about mac.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying a font, not a Unix or Linux issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [Monaco](http://www.fontyukle.net/en/Monaco.ttf) to me.

Also, did you check the name of the default font of Mac OS terminal?

To install the font, create the folder `~/.fonts` and put the font file inside.